# opposite of eject command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, eject

I have a ton of CDs to image, and I just got curious. I can eject with the eject command. What command inserts the disk tray back into the CD drive?

yes it is the type that can pull the tray back in. I searched the eject man page, and guessed at the command, but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To close CD tray with Ubuntu 11.04 or 14.04:

```
eject -t
```

or toggle with

```
eject -T
```

for a summary

```
eject --help
```

Comment: Ah "tray close" i was searching something like insert.

Comment: @j0h also note that some drives don't have the ability to close themselves (laptop style drives for instance - there are desktops that have them, too.)

Comment: sure. like my laptop. when I tried it for giggles, it gave an IO error.

Comment: I don't believe this is version specific. it works the same with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Tested OK on Kubuntu 14.04. But don't forget to specify the drive name, in most cases it will be `eject -t /dev/sr0`.

Comment: Not necessary to state device name.